# What test do I need to use for my dissertation, SPSS?

Tags: repeated-measures, spss

My dissertation question is 'the comparison of cold water immersion and game ready on the alleviation of delayed onset muscle soreness in netball players'.

I have used 15 participants which were split:
5 received cold water immersion
5 received game ready
5 were part of a control group

Scores for delayed onset muscle soreness were given through a visual analogue scale at 5 different stages.. before exercise, immediately after exercise, 24hr post, 48hr post and 72hr post.

I am struggling on which test to perform as I havent used SPSS before

Answer (score 1):

If you have data for all 15 participants at all 15 times, you will want to use a single-between-factor repeated measures ANOVA to test if there is a difference between the three treatment conditions.

**Follow-up from comments below**
Step 1:  From SPSS drop down menus:
      Analyze > General Linear Model > Repeated Measures...
Step 2:  Define the within-subject factors (the repeated things):
      • change Within-Subject Factor Name: to time
      • enter the number of levels: 5
      • click Add and then click Define
      • highlight the variables from the variable list for the repeated measures and click the arrow to move them to the Within-Subjects Variables Block
      • highlight the grouping variable from the variable list and click the arrow to move them to the Between-Subjects Factor(s) block
      • click OK

This should run the requested test.

Comment: Sorry, I really am struggling..
So if there are 3 different groups i do the single-factor-between-factor repeated measures anova?
I thought it was just a repeated measure ANOVA but this makes more sense, but I cant seem to find this option available on SPSS?

Comment: no worries...this is a bit tricky on SPSS. First, let's make sure you data is in the correct format in SPSS. You should have a row for each participant, a variable (column) indicating the group membership, and a separate set of columns for each of the time measurements. So, just to make sure, the data should have 6 columns and 15 rows. Let me know if that makes sense, and we can go from there.

Comment: Also, to clarify, single-factor-between means that individuals are assigned to different groups, and there is only one such set of groups (the factor)...though that factor can have different levels (or categories).  In your case, you have a single factor (treatment group) which has 3 distinct levels (cold H2O, game-ready & control).

Comment: I have correctly inputted data however have a few more columns due to height, weight and age.. All of that makes sense, could you please help me on what to do next?

Comment: Also, is the single-factor-between-factor repeated measures also known as a three way anova?

Comment: I've included a follow-up section in the answer above. Also, this is not a 3-way ANOVA (that is an ANOVA with three factors, where each subject is associated with only one level of each factor).

Comment: Sorry to sound stupid, but which ones do i move in the variables section and which ones go into the grouping variables? I think ive over thinked this so much and confused myself!

Comment: Ideally, you will have a grouping variable indicating which treatment (1=cold,2=game,3=control). This goes into the 2nd block. The first block should have 5 options waiting to be filled...these are the data for the 5 time collection points.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You have helped so much, cant thank you enough!

Comment: Really sorry to be such a pain.. I have ran the test and got the data back however im struggling to see which intervention has a bigger impact? Im not sure if this changes what test I need to do, because it isnt telling me the difference between each variable (as in, CWI, GR and CG) Im sorry im so confused!

Comment: @TaraWilson I'd suggest starting a new question and include your output to ask for assistance with that next.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help, I have posted another question and hopefully i get a response :)